# Woocommerce Variable Product stock quantity update

Tags: php, woocommerce

I tried to use this code to change one particular variation from a variable product.

```
$variation_obj = new  WC_Product_Variation($variation['variation_id']);

$variation_obj->set_manage_stock(true);

$variation_obj->set_stock_quantity((float)0.0);
```

because
[From the woocommerce documentation it says that  set_stock_quantity(), set_stock_status() are methods inherited from WC_Product.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html)

I didn't succeed and used instead update_post_meta.

```
update_post_meta($variation['variation_id'] ,"_manage_stock","yes");
update_post_meta($variation['variation_id'],"_stock", 0);
```

Documentation said that sticking to a table name isn't correct, but i can't find workaround.
What am i doing wrong with set_stock_quantity? It is inherited from the base class but i can't call it.

I don't know what associated hooks should be called to update stock quantity and i am afraid it could break some other plugins. Is it fine to just leave it like this?

Comment: It is very unintuitive to set another

update_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], '_stock_status', 'outofstock');